# avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Tags: ftdi

Arduino IDE is throwing this error when uploading sketches - **avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding**

The problem arose just after I uploaded a blink sketch to my Arduino Mini, which worked absolutely fine. After the successful upload I tried to upload a different sketch and got the error.

I thought I had destroyed the boot loader somehow and was about to get out the Bus Pirate for ICSP but I decided to try another Arduino Mini I had lying around (albeit from another manufacturer) and got the same error.

So I'm convinced it's a driver issue as I successfully uploaded a sketch (it still runs as we speak!) then just magically without changing **ANYTHING** I can no longer upload.

In a futile attempt to get back to work I've done the following:
Switched the RX-TX lines (clearly not the issue as the first upload worked)
Used a different FTDI cable
used a  different programmer
(FTDI 5V/3.3V USB to TTL Basic FT232 FIO Programmer)
(USB to TTL Serial UART RS232 Adaptor (PL2303HX)
I'm fairly certain these use different drivers - FTDI and Prolific

Please help me I'm about to murder something :'(

[Screencaps of error and device manager - Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBQoV.jpg)

Comment: The error appears when you overwrite the bootloader. Only the bootloader makes the standard Upload button work.

Comment: i am having same problem in uno, I checked all of possible situation(board/COM), what to do? and aslo please tell me which programmer I need to choose?

Comment: Answer is below. You need to press the button on the arduino board as you are uploading the sketch.    https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoMini

Comment: Did you check the **pin alignment** of your FTDI connector with the 6-pin connector on your Arduino board? Although the FTDI adapters look the same, the 6-pin connector may actually have been swapped. BTW, my FTDI adapter resolves the need to reset the Arduino before uploading by bringing out the DTR signal on pin 6. However, it was made **backwards** from other ones.

Comment: Please post this as "Comment" because it ISNT an answer!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/40811)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it this?
>
> "To upload a new sketch to the Arduino Mini, you need to press the reset button >on the board immediately before pressing the upload button in the Arduino >environment."
>
> https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoMini

You sir, are a hero.

I don't even know how I accidentally did this sequence to upload the first sketch... Perhaps I plugged the USB to Serial UART in to the USB port and quickly pressed upload? Having got the first sketch on there really mixed me up :/

Solution:

1. Click upload sketch - It will show 'Compiling Sketch'
2. Immediately after clicking upload, hold the reset button down on the Arduino mini
3. Release the reset button when 'Compiling Sketch' turns in to 'Uploading'

Answer (score 4):

Is it this?

"To upload a new sketch to the Arduino Mini, you need to press the reset button on the board immediately before pressing the upload button in the Arduino environment."

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoMini

Answer (score -1):

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

I have the same problem (Arduino uno)
I reset the Arduino several times, but finally i fixed the problem.
so you must change the pic of the arduino and make sure it was instilled correctly on the arduino board.

hope it work...